# What are scenarios that trigger Application_End event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, events

Asp.net has an `Application_End` event which occurs when the application comes to end, like this

```
void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

My question is the following: when does this event occurs in real, i.e. what kind of situations trigger it?

Suppose I have a banking web application running `24x7x365`, which executes continuously & accesses from thousands of places at a time, then when would this `Application_End` event occur? What kinds of situations are responsible for this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `Application_End` event gets fired when the IIS pool is recycled or when you make changes to  the bin folder or web.config file. You should change the default IIS setting to schedule a recycle **once a day** on offpeak hours.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, this answer helped me a lot, I had used an SMS sending function to Send my Mobile phone Text messages in my Application_Start and Application_End events and I wasn't aware that building my web service causes the Application to fire Start and End events, and I was receiving rapid Messages :) your answer helped me understand what was happening. Thanks.

Comment: "when you make changes to the bin folder" was the issue for me. I was writing out a debugging text file to the BIN directory during a certain situation and it kept kicking me out of the web app (i.e. closing my session and application_end() firing. This was driving me nuts so thanks for this little snippet.

Comment: @StefanP: If you have to purposely schedule a recycle, then there is a problem with your application.  You shouldn't ever have to repeatedly restart/recycle.  If there is an issue that causes you to consider that, then you need to investigate and fix  *THAT* issue instead of placing a band-aid on it by scheduling a recycle.

Answer (score 10):

**It will be fired in one of those situations:**

1. IIS pool is restarted.
2. Web.config changes.
3. Application is restarted.