# Handle close event of browser in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to handle close event of browser(cross browser).And I need call a function from aspx.cs page when the event is called and also end the existing session.Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961544/chrome-detect-when-browser-exits

Comment: There's no guarantee your code will execute in time, your best bet is to detect an inactive session on the server side and end it that way.

Comment: I need to show list of Logged in users and their log in times.So i am storing the log in time and user id in the database.And when the user log off from the web application I am deleting that user log in time details from the table.But if user close the browser with out logging off then the problem is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

You can set timeout for session and write your code inside the session_ends function in global.aspx file.

Try this:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1116238.aspx?End+Session+When+Browser+Closed

Comment: Doesn't fire at all unless the mode is InProc or Custom and even then it's not guaranteed to fire http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatemodule.end(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Will it be fine if I go for Global.asax.When did Application_end fires?

Comment: From my knowledge global.asax is the only option to handle this. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217704/what-are-scenarios-that-trigger-application-end-event